# Recreate iOS 13' share sheet modal in swift (not the share sheet itself, but the way it's presented)

Tags: ios, swift

is there a way to easily recreate the modal presentation style of ios 13' new share sheet? (At first, it's only presented halfway and you can swipe up to make it a "full" modal sheet) I can do it using a completely custom presentation and stuff but is there a "native" api for this behavior so that you don't have to use custom code?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Isn’t it just a frozen interactive version of the normal sheet presentation?

Comment: Not entirely, the background doesn't start shrinking until you swipe up to make it an actual modal sheet.

Comment: I looked into this and can share what I learned. I think what it comes down to is somehow getting the modally presented view controller to respect the `preferredContentSize` you set... if you inspect view hierarchy the root VC on the system share sheet is presented using a `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet`, then there's an embedded navVC/activityVC that both are presented with a `.pageSheet` style. I can confirm there are no transition or interaction controllers of any kind, and although the system uses a slightly different `UIPresentationController` the values on both are identical

Comment: I confirmed that only the root VC for the system share sheet (the one presented with `.formSheet` has a custom `preferredContentSize` and the children ones do not, so I think it only matters on the original presented VC. I tried overriding `size(forChildContentContainer: withParentContainerSize:)` on the view controller presenting the child, and I tried setting the `preferredContentSize` like ALL over the view lifecycle on the child, but although the value can be inspected to exist, it doesn't respect it. Transition style on default + system both default (vertical).

Comment: Theres also no vertical constraints with heights, it seems to be exclusively bc of `preferredContentSize`. While typically used for `.popover` style, docs in theory say this should be supported "in some cases" too: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621476-preferredcontentsize. Perhaps noodling with some of the other methods in the `UIContentContainer` might help? (`viewWillTransition(to:with:)`)

Comment: If you look at the private properties on the `UIPresentationController` there's also a `__presentsAtStandardHalfHeight = false` if that was true maybe we could just say not possible with non private API but its false for every VC in the system share sheet

Comment: @gadu well if not possible except for private api then it's still possible for custom implementation and this one would be a big winner in terms of how many wuold use it

Comment: FYi, apple isn't using screenshots, they are actually scaling the presentation controller to make this work. i checked in browser with countdown timer website and the count down timer continued to tick when scaled. so this isnt' done by screenshotting anything

Comment: Custom implementation would be pretty straight forward if you're willing to implement either your own animation transitioning delegate, or just using a container VC with a pan gesture to do it yourself - it gets a bit tedious for sure though.

Comment: yeah @gadu, i've locked down everything except mimicking the same interaction that apple has with collectionviews and other scrollviews, but havent' touchecd the scaled animation backing yet. the swiping to lock to top and middle then dismiss is pretty straightforward. i'm thinking the animation of the scale down shouldnt' be too hard either, but it's the making the pan gesture work with the scrollview and locking the scroll at specific times while panning the view up and down which is the rough part.

Comment: another note, if anyone wants to collaborate on this, let me know. i have the code for presentation and the scaling for full screen presentation, so the base code is done, including the fromViewController scaling, just need to add the percent driven animation, the 1/2 screen presentation, and then the playing nice with scrollviews inside the presnted viewcontroller for dismissing

Comment: @Loxx let's collaborate! I just started building this myself and have some pieces working, would love to take a look at what you've got

Comment: @NSExceptional let's do it, give me a few days and i'll hit you back

Comment: @Loxx sounds good, how do you want to get in touch?

Answer (score 34):

Here's what I've tried. I've created a new ViewController class extending UIActivityViewController. And in the viewDidLoad function, I removed all the child views from the controller and added my viewController as a child to it. It seems to be working fine. Although, it is more of a work around it is still sufficient enough for the requirement it seems. Code snippet is as follows. Give it a try.

```
import UIKit

class CustomActivityViewController: UIActivityViewController {

    private let controller: UIViewController!

    required init(controller: UIViewController) {
        self.controller = controller
        super.init(activityItems: [], applicationActivities: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let subViews = self.view.subviews
        for view in subViews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        self.addChild(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    }

}
```

Above is the CustomActivityViewController. And you can add your viewController into it as follows.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController")
let activityViewController = CustomActivityViewController(controller: controller)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: very very interesting, you did good, let me take a look at this later, i didn't even think about subbing a UIActivityViewController

Comment: my god, it looks like you may hav e solved it with a few lines of code, lol, okay, give me a few hours and let me check this out

Comment: one think i wonder is how pissed off would apple be if this is used for this intention we're using it for? do we suppose they'll remove this ability in the future? it seems like the UIActivityViewController isn't meant for random content like this. i would use this for whatever i wish, not just presenting activity items outside the app. i would use it to present options within the app. this is despite you solving it, these are just additional questions we should address. if this solves it you solved it for everyone in the entire app space that has struggled to do this, big apps, small apps, et

Comment: Apple's UIActivityViewController itself is an UIViewController only at the end of everything. And they themselves have only provided a way to add a viewController as a child to another viewController. So, I don't find anything wrong or lawbreaking in using these things to achieve what we need.

Comment: I confirm this is working as expected and I don't see any problem using an UIActivityViewController like this, you are using an existing UIViewController to display custom content without using any private API.

Comment: yep, i just tried it as well, works perfectly, now we have to get the original poster to accept this answer and @SubramanianMariappan gets his 500.

Comment: You can manually award the bounty without the answer being accepted by the original owner: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/19/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: Be careful with this method. One of the issues with overriding Apple's private view hierarchies is undefined states when layout has to be performed. For example, when the user interface changes, background changes, applications uninstalled while in background, etc.

Comment: @LeoNatan--reinstateMonica that's actually a valid point, i'm going to hold off to test both methods then see what we figure out here. the right way to do this is to make our own implementation entirely which is what i've been working on, just need to add the ability to make scrollview work well with the pan gesture and percent driven dragging like apple does and then i have the raw implementation set up. we'll see which method is smoother in a few days

Comment: I don’t think there would be any problem with this as what we are doing is just adding a viewController as a child of another viewController only which is very common in use.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan You are also adding a child view to a system-managed view hierarchy. If you want to see a very easy example of how things break, add a child view controller to a tab bar controller and then add it's view to the hierarchy. Everything breaks. Similarly, if you add to a navigation controller, you can break it very easily.

Comment: Both tab bar controller and navigation controller are functioning upon the list of view controllers added to them. That could be an important factor which cause the breakage. But here things are simple and hence I guess there would be no issues with it.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan I wasn't saying your solution is a bad one. Like we used to use UIToolbar for blurring before the UIVisualEffectView became public API, it's a nice hack. But here it is a much more complex hack, which is why I recommended testing thoroughly. :)

Comment: Work great but be careful because I tried it on iOS 12 and it's awful.
It is not guarantee it will work for futur version of iOS

Comment: This seems like the best option to recreate the share sheet so far, has anyone figured out how to change the initial height of `CustomActivityViewController`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in private API, this is how Apple does it:

There is a class named [`_UISheetDetent`](https://github.com/LeoNatan/Apple-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/iOS/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/_UISheetDetent.h). With this class, you can either create system defined "detents"—medium and large—or provide your own block-based logic (input param is the presentation controller's container view, and the return value is a double—the percent to open the sheet).

You create an array of these "detents" and provide them to the sheet presentation controller using the [`_setDetents:`](https://github.com/LeoNatan/Apple-Runtime-Headers/blob/4614425d614004f6d215cc719bb93c0d210972f9/iOS/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/_UISheetPresentationController.h#L124) method (or `setValue:forKey:`). To replicate the share sheet behavior, you need an array with two "detents": medium and large.

There is also the [`_indexOfLastUndimmedDetent`](https://github.com/LeoNatan/Apple-Runtime-Headers/blob/4614425d614004f6d215cc719bb93c0d210972f9/iOS/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/_UISheetPresentationController.h#L122) property, which controls which "detent" starts the dimming process.

I'm not sure why Apple hasn't exposed this as public API. It is concise, simple and works well.

You should **probably** not use this API, but if you decide to use it, it should be very easy to hide it. In any case, make sure to open a Feedback with Apple to expose this API in a future version of the SDK.

Comment: that's very interesting as well. i'm gonna give this a go too. and this isn't too outside of private API use where they'd freak out on app approval. I may try this in a dummy app fro app store upload to see what they say. but yes, Ill be submitting feedback to apple to expose this, it works in ipad without this trickery, so it would seem like a no brainer that they expose it for iphones as well. thanks again

Comment: If you go this route, use minimal effort to hide it, just for their automated tools to miss.